# Have tmux wait until I SSH in, to complete rest of Tmuxinator script

Tags: linux, ssh, tmux

After recently discovering tmux and Tmuxinator, I've been trying to set up a development environment to use.

Per protocol, we aren't allowed to store passwords/passphrases in scripts.  So what I'm looking for is a wait for tmux to wait for the SSH tunnel to get set up (password supplied, enter pressed, and logged in).

I know that there's a "wait-for" command in tmux 1.8+.  I'm running 1.9a via Cygwin.  But even though I've read over the documentation, I'm just having a difficult time understanding it.

```
tmux new-session -s development -n editor -d
tmux split-window -v
tmux split-window -v

"Need to send to all panes.
tmux send-keys -t development 'ssh user@example.com' C-m
```

So, here's a very simple version of what I have.

Thoughts?  I know I can synchronize-sessions, I'm still working out the kinks in this.

**Edit**:
Looking into commands, and pulling variables from the pane to the command from synchronized-panes.  This might be a "better" way to go about, until I can figure out how to get TMUX to prompt me for user-input.

Might issue a feature request.

Comment: Why don't you connect without the password and use public/private key?

Comment: I was told that I couldn't connect that way.  While I technically *could*, it isn't acceptable with the policies that have been put in place.  I also have no voice/authority to make that change (quickly?) either.  So in my case, in examining the roads of least resistance, this seems to have promise.

Comment: I take it that the remote box doesn't have tmux installed? Otherwise it would be much better to ssh into the remote box and *only then* launch tmux. // Also, I'd suggest that you make use of your `~/.ssh/config` file: put `Host foo`, `User user` and `Hostname example.com` on three consecutive lines in the config file. Then `ssh foo` becomes equivalent to `ssh user@example.com`. // Maybe something like this helps, too: `command-prompt -p 'log in as:' -I 'user@example.com' 'split-window -v -d %1; split-window -v -d %1'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Some notes of `wait-for`

So the basic usage of wait-for isn't too complicated if you think of it as analogous to threading [concurrency primitives](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hgs/os/sync.html)

It's not really connected to other tmux functionality, just a convenient implementation of IPC.

`wait-for event_name` is like waiting for an *event*
`wait-for -S event_name`  is a means of signalling an *event*

The `-U` and `-L` options are kind of orthogonal and act like *semaphores*

## Addressing your question directly

You can solve these sorts of race condition with `wait-for` but only if commands are synchronous.

```
tmux send-keys 'sync-command ; tmux wait-for -S command-finished' C-m
tmux wait-for command-finished
```

The problem that you have here is that ssh command isn't synchronous: you can't tell when it has finished.

Looking through [the manual](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) we can find the `LocalCommand` directive which seems to do what we want: run a command locally after the connection has finished so we can call

```
ssh root@iris.tatw.name -o 'PermitLocalCommand yes' -o 'LocalCommand  tmux wait-for -S done'
```

Comment: So by "not connected to other functionality" you mean the `channel` is just a name in its own namespace and unrelated to tmux's predefined "events"?

Comment: There might still be a race issue if `wait-for -S` doesn't guarantee message delivery and the `sync-command` finishes before `wait-for`.